# CS0266 error in C#. Need advise with adding int and double together.

Tags: c#, int, double

```
 {
            int priceforprimer = 0;
            double H, L, W, Finthearea = 0;

            priceforprimer = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);
            H = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            L = double.Parse(textBox6.Text);
            W = double.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            Finthearea = H * L * W;

            priceforprimer = Finthearea / 13;

            textBox8.Text = Finthearea.ToString();
```

Hello, my assignment is to work out the area of the wall and then work out how many tins of primer is needed for that wall exactly as "Paint is purchased as full tins of paint only." The double values work and I can calculate the area, but the division doesn't. Per 13m of wall works out as one tin of primer. I have been trying for 2 hours with this, but I am lost, also pretty new to C# which makes it trickier. Thanks.

Comment: Your price of primer is an int and not a double?

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Something like a price which requires decimal precision should probably not be an `int`. Also, you are setting `priceforprimer` twice -- the parsing of textBox9 is unnecessary (or incorrect here). It would really help if your variable names were more explanatory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You should have two hours worth of material to show on what you've tried.

Comment: Did you output the value for _Finthearea_ instead of _priceforprimer_?

Comment: Here's a hint once you solve the current data type problem: you're going to need a `Math.Ceiling()` call in here somewhere. If your calculation comes out to needing 1.0001 tins of paint, that still means you need 2 full tins. `Math.Ceiling(1.0001)` will be `2.0`.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I have figured it out, but how do I use the Math.Ceiling? I have never used it before. valforprimer = val3 / 13; it comes out on the textbox as a huge number ?

Answer (score 0):

//These are typical ceiling samples in C#.  You also need to adopt naming //conventions in your code (i.e names like textbox5 are not standard)

```
     using System;
      class Program
       {
         static void Main()
          {
              // Get ceiling of double value.
       double value1 = 123.456;
    double ceiling1 = Math.Ceiling(value1);

    // Get ceiling of decimal value.
    decimal value2 = 456.789M;
    decimal ceiling2 = Math.Ceiling(value2);

    // Get ceiling of negative value.
    double value3 = -100.5;
    double ceiling3 = Math.Ceiling(value3);

    // Write values.
    Console.WriteLine(value1);
    Console.WriteLine(ceiling1);
    Console.WriteLine(value2);
    Console.WriteLine(ceiling2);
    Console.WriteLine(value3);
    Console.WriteLine(ceiling3);
     }
  }
```